# About state_focused and state_pressed?

Tags: android

Is it possible for a button in such state:

```
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/unfocused_pressed" />
```

How would it not in the focused state when is pressed?

Comment: @GhostDerfel not answer my question,if a button is pressed ,so it always focused?

Comment: state_focused is whenever the button is focused on using a dpad or the trackball. Views don't generally show a focused state when using touch.